# $(...).cells is undefined in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have two forms, form1 contains the date and the display button, the show button allows you to hide the form1 and display the form2, the form2 contains the chosen date and a datatable with checkboxes and button valider, i want when i click the show button console show matricules of salaries.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#check_all').on('click', function(e) {
    if ($(this).is(':checked', true)) {
      $(".checkbox").prop('checked', true);
    } else {
      $(".checkbox").prop('checked', false);
    }
  });
  
  $('.checkbox').on('click', function() {
    if ($('.checkbox:checked').length == $('.checkbox').length) {
      $('#check_all').prop('checked', true);
    } else {
      $('#check_all').prop('checked', false);
    }
  });
  
  $("#form2").hide();
  
  $("#hide").click(function() {
    $("#form1").hide();
    $("#form2").show();
    let dat = $("#dateS").val();
    $("#da").text(dat);
    
    $("tr").each(function(i, r) {
      let mat = $(r).cells[2].innerText;
      console.log(mat);
    });
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- form 1 -->
<div id="form1">
  <div class=" col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
      <label for="titre">date</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-5">
      <input type="date" name="dateS" id="dateS" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" id="hide" data-url="">show</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- form 2 -->
<div id="form2">
  <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
    <h4>dateS : <span id="da"></span></h4>
  </div>
  <table class="table table-bordered" id="mytable">
    <tr>
      <th><input type="checkbox" id="check_all"></th>
      <th>nom</th>
      <th>matricule</th>
      <th>adresse</th>
      <th>prime</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"></td>
      <td>najib</td>
      <td>52</td>
      <td>tihit</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="prime" class="form-control prime" value="0"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"></td>
      <td>adil</td>
      <td>62</td>
      <td>tagmast</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="prime" class="form-control prime" value="0"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div class="form-group col-md-offset-5 ">
    <button class="btn btn-success add-all" type="submit" id="hide">valider</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: jQuery objects don't have a `cells` array. Use `r.cells[2].innerText;` or `$(r).children('td:eq(2), th:eq(2)').text();`

Comment: wouldn't it be `r.cells`? ie you want the non jquery object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `$(r).cells[2].innerText` use jQuery

```
$(r).find('td').eq(2).text()
```

or:

```
$(this).find('td:eq(2)').text();
```

---

`cells` is used in vanilla JavaScript to get the *cells* from TableRowElement, while your `$(r)` is a reference to a collection of elements wrapped into a jQuery object

therefore if you want to use JavaScript you still can, but like:

```
r.cells[2].textContent
```

also, notice the use of the preferred `textContent` vs `innerText`